# Compiling CImage::StretchBlt() always always shows Internal compiler error in x64

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, 32bit-64bit

Environment : VS2008 SP1 Professional

I have a function which uses the method CImage::StretchBlt(). The code compiles correctly in 32 bit environment, but in 64bit, it always show the error

> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlimage.h(398) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

```
void CMyListView::DrawHistoryThumbnail( int nIndex )
{
    CRect rctThumbnail;
    GetThumbnailRect( rctThumbnail );

    CImage imgHistory;
    imgHistory.LoadFromResource( AfxGetResourceHandle(), IDB_BITMAP_HISTORY_THUMBNAIL ); 

    CDC* pDC = GetDC();
    CDC dcMemory;
    dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC( pDC );

    CBitmap bmpHistory;
    bmpHistory.CreateCompatibleBitmap( pDC, rctThumbnail.Width(), rctThumbnail.Height() );

    CBitmap* pOldBmp = dcMemory.SelectObject( &bmpHistory );

    // if comment the below issue goes away
    imgHistory.StretchBlt( dcMemory.GetSafeHdc(), rctThumbnail, SRCCOPY );

    CBrush brushFrame;  
    brushFrame.CreateSolidBrush( RGB(0, 0, 255) );
    dcMemory.FrameRect( rctThumbnail, &brushFrame );

    dcMemory.SelectObject( pOldBmp );
    ReleaseDC( pDC );
}
```

Comment: Signal this to Microsoft and/or consider upgrading to a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Update: Removing the /clr option from the project setting fixed the issue.